# How can I find where my files have gone - Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-home-server

Today I have looked on my homeserver and a single folder holding all my photos has gone from one of my shares on my homeserver, fortunately everything is backed up, but what it the best way to see what has happened.

I have run CheckDisk, rebooted my machine and run recuva, none of which shows any problems or can find any files.

Also WHS and explorer is still saying the folder contains 70gb of data but no files are shown

Comment: Are the files just no longer visible to clients, or have you actually remote-desktopped on to the server, and looked there?

Comment: Both, weirdly they appear from one client machine, but not RDP'd into the machine and not from another client

Comment: The only thing I could think of was something might have marked lots of files as Hidden - and then whether you could see them depended on whether you had "Show Hidden Files" enabled.